# virtual box version 5.0.4 Failed to create the VirtualBoxClient COM object.

Tags: virtualbox

i installed genymotion version 2.5.4 package with virtual box version 5.0.4. However the virtual box could not function. It comes out with error.

Failed to create the VirtualBoxClient COM object.

The application will now terminate.

Callee RC: REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG (0x80040154)

I have tried to reinstall but not luck. Here the log file of virtual box.

```
VirtualBox COM Server 5.0.4 r102546 win.amd64 (Sep  8 2015 10:46:49) release log
00:00:00.006000 main     Log opened 2015-11-18T13:46:28.173803900Z
00:00:00.006000 main     Build Type: release
00:00:00.006000 main     OS Product: Windows 7
00:00:00.006000 main     OS Release: 6.1.7600
00:00:00.006000 main     OS Service Pack: 
00:00:00.037002 main     DMI Product Name: Inspiron N5110
00:00:00.049002 main     DMI Product Version: Not Specified
00:00:00.049002 main     Host RAM: 4003MB total, 1741MB available
00:00:00.049002 main     Executable: C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\VBoxSVC.exe
00:00:00.049002 main     Process ID: 6520
00:00:00.049002 main     Package type: WINDOWS_64BITS_GENERIC
00:00:00.052002          Home directory: 'C:\Users\User 20-01-2014/.VirtualBox'
00:00:00.206011          usbLibDevCfgDrGet: DeviceIoControl 1 fail winEr (31)
00:00:00.213012          USB: Unknown USB device detected (idVendor: 0x0000, idProduct: 0x0000). Please, report the idVendor and idProduct to virtualbox.org.
00:00:00.213012          USB: Unknown USB device detected (idVendor: 0x0000, idProduct: 0x0000). Please, report the idVendor and idProduct to virtualbox.org.
00:00:00.253014          Skipped non-Ethernet 'Loopback Pseudo-Interface 1'
00:00:00.253014          Skipped non-Ethernet 'Local Area Connection* 11'
00:00:00.253014          Skipped non-Ethernet 'isatap.{DA53AD29-3A42-4681-8970-EA104A7A59EA}'
00:00:00.253014          Skipped non-Ethernet '6TO4 Adapter'
00:00:00.253014          Skipped non-Ethernet 'isatap.{13F37373-5B94-4591-849E-4C2F0CFEC644}'
00:00:00.253014          Skipped non-Ethernet 'isatap.{A0FA46F7-BBD1-4D4F-A153-582E4A9FF470}'
00:00:00.253014          Skipped non-Ethernet 'isatap.{3B262A5D-979C-43CC-BBE9-85F6D3B5FF05}'
00:00:00.253014          Skipped non-Ethernet 'isatap.{1CD1246A-DE08-41B3-B52E-9EE9EA1F8C27}'
00:00:00.275015          HostDnsMonitor: old information
00:00:00.275015            no server entries
00:00:00.275015            no search string entries
00:00:00.275015            no domain set
00:00:00.275015          HostDnsMonitor: new information
00:00:00.275015            server 1: 192.168.43.1
00:00:00.275015            no search string entries
00:00:00.275015            no domain set
00:00:00.275015          HostDnsMonitorProxy::notify
00:00:00.724041          VD: VDInit finished
00:00:05.768329 Watcher  ERROR [COM]: aRC=E_ACCESSDENIED (0x80070005) aIID={0169423f-46b4-cde9-91af-1e9d5b6cd945} aComponent={VirtualBoxWrap} aText={The object is not ready}, preserve=false aResultDetail=0
```

Answer (score 1):

in VBoxSVC.log you have error like this:
Watcher  ERROR [COM]: aRC=E_ACCESSDENIED (0x80070005) aIID={0169423f-46b4-cde9-91af-1e9d5b6cd945} aComponent={VirtualBoxWrap} aText={The object is not ready}, preserve=false aResultDetail=0

you have a key: {0169423f-46b4-cde9-91af-1e9d5b6cd945} and you dont have a permission to that key
use registry editor and set "Full control" for Administrators to that key and subkeys in it

sorry for my english :) I dont use it to often

sg

Answer (score 0):

- > Open registory editor (open RUN -> type regedit) then find for given key (key - aIID={0169423f-46b4-cde9-91af-1e9d5b6cd945})
  >   change
  >   its permission and restart machine.
- > If above won't work then make sure that you don't have VMWare-horixon-client installed in your system. For my System this
  >   was
  >   the problem and after that its working fine.